# Silverlight app has cpu between 20% and 40%

Tags: silverlight

I do not know much about Silverlight but an app I am trying to maintain has the cpu constantly hitting between 20% to 40%.

The app is just showing data from a database and I believe the developer refreshes the page every minute but in between cpu is still at 20%.

I am trying to argue that this looks a bit high but the response I get back is that it is normal.

Any counter arguments I can give?

JD

Answer (score 2):

You can find some performance tips from Microsoft [at this page here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189071%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

When I was developing a resource intensive Silverlight application a few months back, I found it useful to set the [MaxFrameRate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838147%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). I'm not sure on the details of your application, but if it is redrawing frequently, this will definitely help.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Without knowing too much about silverlight, all we have is a simple database application (CRUD), so my initial impression after seeing all the CPU being used on the browser as a major issue.